# Create a child form and modify parent at same time, Django

Tags: django, forms, parent

I have two models connected with a foreignkey parent and child, i would be able to create a child data  and modify at the same time a field present in a parent model.
thanks for any help

'''
models.py

```
class Richieste(models.Model):
    SCELTA_1 = [
        ('Estero', 'Estero'),
        ('Italia', 'Italia'),
    ]

    STATO = [
        ('In lavorazione', 'In lavorazione'),
        ('Chiuso esito POSITIVO', 'Chiuso esito POSITIVO'),
        ('Chiuso esito NEGATIVO', 'Chiuso esito NEGATIVO'),
    ]

    TIPO_PRODOTTO = [
        ('Esterno', 'Esterno'),
        ('Interno', 'Interno'),
    ]

    titolo = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Indica Argomento/Agenzia richiedente')
    contenuto = models.TextField()
    data_creazione = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    scelta_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SCELTA_1, help_text='ITALI/ESTERO', verbose_name = "provenienza")
    stato = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATO, default='In lavorazione' , blank = True, help_text='Stato richiesta')
    tipo_prodotto = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TIPO_PRODOTTO, blank = False, help_text='Esterno/Interno')
    protocollo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True) #default='SOME STRING'
    allegato = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads//%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True, null=True, verbose_name = "allega documenti")
    allegato_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads//%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True, null=True, verbose_name = "allega immagini")
    autore = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.titolo} {0.autore} '
        return template.format(self)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('speciali-home')

class Discussione(models.Model):
    risposta = models.ForeignKey(Richieste, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contenuto = models.TextField()
    data_risposta = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    allegato = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads//%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True, null=True)
    elaboratore = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    
    def __str__(self):
        template = '{0.risposta} {0.elaboratore} '
        return template.format(self)
```

'''
when i create a Discussione form everithing work fine but in the same form i wanto to change the 'Stato' of the parent model 'Richieste'

'''
forms.py

```
class DiscRispModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #stato = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Richieste.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Discussione
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, risposta_id=None, elaboratore_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DiscRispModelForm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["risposta"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields["elaboratore"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields["data_risposta"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
       

        if risposta_id:
            self.fields['risposta'].initial = risposta_id

        if elaboratore_id:
            self.fields['elaboratore'].initial = elaboratore_id
```

'''

'''
views.py

```
class DiscCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Discussione
    template_name = 'discussione_nuova.html'
    form_class = DiscRispModelForm



def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # we need to overwrite get_context_data
        # to make sure that our formset is rendered
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data["children"] = RichiesteForm(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data["children"] = RichiesteForm()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        children = context["children"]
        self.object = form.save()
        if children.is_valid():
            children.instance = self.object
            children.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


    




    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('speciali-richiesta-singola', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs.get('pk')})


    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['risposta_id'] = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        kwargs['elaboratore_id'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override the child model's save() method and modify the parent according to the changes. I can't give you an example without an example of your models.

Edit:
In your case, you can add an extra field in your ModelForm and override the ModelForm's `save()` method:

```
class DiscRispModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    stato = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [('In lavorazione', 'In lavorazione'),('Chiuso esito POSITIVO', 'Chiuso esito POSITIVO'),('Chiuso esito NEGATIVO', 'Chiuso esito NEGATIVO')])

    class Meta:
        model = Discussione
        fields = '__all__'

def __init__(self, risposta_id=None, elaboratore_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(DiscRispModelForm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["risposta"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields["elaboratore"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields["data_risposta"].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
   

    if risposta_id:
        self.fields['risposta'].initial = risposta_id

    if elaboratore_id:
        self.fields['elaboratore'].initial = elaboratore_id

def save(self, commit=True):
    # do something with self.cleaned_data['stato'] like:
    self.instance.risposta.stato = self.cleaned_data['stato']
    self.instance.risposta.save()

    return super(DiscRispModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

Comment: Thank you Paul for your reply, i post the code, i want to higlight that this is my first project in django I have no experience before in coding so please if you have an advice make it accuraccy because all the little things for me are crucial

Comment: Ok, what is your logic for denying or approving a request?

Comment: this is a decision of the "Elaboratore" (child model) that analyzing the request can avoid or accept the request

Comment: tks but what is model = Point?

Comment: Copy/paste mistake.

Comment: diesn't work, first problem  stato=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Richieste.objects.all())..give me not the "stato" choicefield but the reference foreignkey "Richeste" and second there is no attribute "stato" in self.instance.risposta.stato because stato is in Richieste model, i tryed to change but dosen't work too

Comment: i have no words ...thank you very much Paul as we said here in Italy "tu sei il numero uno" all the best